# What is the general solution of $xy'+2y=\sin x$?

Tags: integration

I assume that we all know the [general solution of inhomogeneous first-order linear ODE](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/solution-by-integrating-factors/MIT18_03SCF11_s5_1text.pdf) is:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)\Rightarrow y=e^{-\int P(x)\,dx}\left ( \int Q(x)\cdot e^{\int P(x)\,dx}\,dx+\text{const.} \right )$$

, and then I tried to solve the ODE by it.

This is what I've done:

[image]

But why the solution is a little bit different from the answer provided from this book and [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%27%2B2y%3Dsinx)?

Thanks.

**note**: $c_{1}$ to $c_{5}$ are all constant, but they are different.

Comment: You do not have to add arbitrary constants to the integrals. The solution to the first order differential equation depends on only one arbitrary constant as it is shown in the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only use one indefinite integral $A(x)=\int a(x)dx$ in the solution formula $e^{-A(x)}$ of the homogeneous equation differential $y'+a(x)y(x)=0$ and the integrating factor $e^{A(x)}$ inside and outside the integral of the inhomogeneous solution. So really, $C_2=C_3$ and $C_4=C_5$, so these constants cancel in the first part, and only the one constant $const=C_1/C_5$ remains.